# How to determine what jQuery event caused form post back in MVC

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in which I am selecting an employee from using an autocomplete and perform some complex task based on the selection. Therefore I post back form on the change event of text box.

Here is my Begin form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeEdit","Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EmployeeEditView" }))
```

This is the text box for which I want to post back form on the change event.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.CurveToBeProxied, new { id = "txtSearchEmployee" })
```

Here is the code of Change event

```
$('#txtSearchEmployee').change(function () {
    alert("Hi");
    $('#EmployeeEditView').submit();
});
```

Here is the controller action. It works well for post back from btnSelectEmployee and btnUnSelectEmployee button click but not for text box change event. I dont know how to identify the change event.

```
public ActionResult EmployeeEdit(EmployeeEditViewModel model, string btnSelectEmployee, string btnUnSelectEmployee, string txtSearchEmployee)
{
    //if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(btnSelectEmployee))
    //{
    //    SelectScenario(model);
    //}
    //else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(btnUnSelectEmployee))
    //{
    //    UnSelectScenario(model);
    //}
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Change should work, do you see the `alert('hi')` at all?

Comment: What are you trying to do on your change event on the server? Because full postbacks are something we'll advise you not to do if possible. Ajax requests would be a much better choice to accomplish a much better user experience in MVC.

Comment: Why are your `if` conditions identical? Wouldn't just `else` be enough?

Comment: If you're using `TextBoxFor` don't manipulate IDs. They'll be correctly set to your model for later data binding on the server without the need to provide individual controller action parameters but rather view model only.

Comment: **BTW:** if you have **strong typed views** and you're **setting IDs to individual controls** that are populated from the model, you're likely doing something wrong. Or not understanding how Asp.net MVC works...

Answer (score 1):

The change event will fire when the input box looses **focus**. Try pressing tab.

Or...try using the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/v) event:

```
$('#txtSearchEmployee').keyup(function () { 
    var newValue = $('#txtSearchEmployee').val();       
    if(newValue === oldValue) // as RobertKoritnik suggested, check whether the value has changed in order to account for non-character keys such as arrow
       return false;

    oldValue = newValue;

    alert("Hi");
    $('#EmployeeEditView').submit();
});
```

**Update**: How to determine what HTML element fired the HTTP request?

One way to do this could be to add a hidden field that will specify what element is causing the form submit.

For example, add it to your model and then create field like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ElementId, )
```

Then set its value, just before submitting the form:

```
$('#txtSearchEmployee').change(function () {
    alert("Hi");
    $('#ElementId').val('txtSearchEmployee'); //set field that is causing the form submit
    $('#EmployeeEditView').submit();
});
```

You should be able to retrieve this value from your model on your controller.

Comment: In `keyup` you should actually check that value has changed. What if user only pressed *arrow*, *end* or *home* key? But you're likely correct that OP is expecting change event to fire on every keystroke and not on focus change... So +1 for that.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik good point, it is worth mentioning. I'll include this in my answer.

Comment: I think my post was confusing. The form is getting submitted on text change but how to determine in controller that form was submitted by button clicks or by text change event. When button say btnSelectEmployee is clicked the action parameter btnSelectEmployee is populated. That does not happed with text change.